# Hook's useState initial value never changes in callback that is memoized

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In this simple example, I am memoizing Child component using *useMemo* and passing *callback* back to parent function to add data to react hook array, which is initially set as empty.

My question is as follows: Why hook *data* never changes and keeps it's initial state in callback function that comes from Child component which is memoized. However, when checking *data* hook in *useEffect* method or using that hook in rendering - it always has the newest state.

It is more of a general question what happens behind the hood and what is the best way, for example, to check against duplicate values in callback functions from memoized child components if *data* always has initial state.

I am aware of *useReducer* and that I can manipulate data in *hooks* setter method before adding it, but maybe there are other methods?

**Parent component:**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import Child from "./Child";

function App() {

const [data, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("UseEffect", data)
},[data]);

return (
<div>
  <Child callback={(val)=>{
      console.log("Always returns initial state", data);  // <----------Why?
      setData(old=>{
          console.log("Return previous state", old);
            return [...old, val]
      })
  }} />

   Length: {data.length /*Always gets updated*/}
</div>
);
}

export default App;
```

Child component: In real scenario it is a map, that I want to render only once, without causing re-renders.

```
import React, {useMemo} from "react"

export default function Child({callback}) {
return useMemo(()=>{
    return <button onClick={()=>callback(1)}>
        Press!
    </button>
},[])
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect updated value before setData?

Comment: I don't expect updated value before setData, but it never changes even after multiple callbacks received, which means that setData was already called before, but hook didn't change

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you need to pass `data` as props and use it in your second argument of useMemo.

Comment: setData doesn't mutate original data array, it return a new array reference. you are not passing down new data reference, given you use memo. once you use memo, you have the first data reference, and it keeps that way forever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to return new reference of callback, without adding dependencies in useMemo method

Like this

```
// returns *(always the same)* function that will forward the call to the latest passed `callback`
function useFunction(callback) {
  const ref = React.useRef();
  ref.current = callback;

  return React.useCallback(function() {
    const callback = ref.current;
    if (typeof callback === "function") {
      return callback.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  }, []);
}
```

and then:

```
export function Child({ callback }) {
  const handler = useFunction(callback);

  return useMemo(() => {
    return <button onClick={() => handler(1)}>Press!</button>;
  }, []);
}
```

or

```
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const callback = useFunction((val) => {
    console.log("Always returns the latest state", data);
    setData([...data, val]);
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <Child callback={callback} />

     Length: {data.length /*Always gets updated*/}
    </div>
  );
}

function Child({ callback }) {
  return useMemo(() => {
    return <button onClick={() => callback(1)}>
      Press!
      </button>
  }, [])
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks - this was exactly what I needed to get an updated state inside a memoized callback.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, your `Child` component is **memoized**, which means it will **only** update if one of its dependency changes.
So at the first rendering, you create your `Child` component with the function you pass to the `callback` prop, and at this time, `data` is `[]`. If you click on the button, `data` is updated correctly and so is the function passed to `callback` prop to `Child`, but since you did not set any dependency to `useMemo`, your `Child` component will **not update** and will still return its memoized version, with first callback prop it received, which indeed always log the initial value of `data`: `[]`.

So all you need is to add `callback` to the list of dependencies of `useMemo`:

```
export function Child({ callback }) {
  return useMemo(() => {
    return <button onClick={() => callback(1)}>Press!</button>;
  }, [callback]);
}
```

This way, when the `callback` prop changes, your `Child` component will also update its `onClick` event handler.

Also, I recommend using [eslint-plugin-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react) npm package, which will instantly warn you about missing dependencies in React hooks, and more generally about bad practices in your code.

Comment: It will not work. The `callback` prop will never change. Pass `data` and use it.

Comment: It does work, `callback` prop actually changes at every render.

Comment: What if child component is, for instance, a google map that I don't want to update it, because it will cause re-renders. Is there some other approach?

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure.

Comment: @Benas.M can you be a bit more specific ? I'm not sure I understand correctly what you want.

Comment: This approach would cause re-renders to child component, but it will also update the hook in parent component. The thing is, I want to render child component(map) only first time, because it is a google map and I don't want to re-render it.

Comment: Okay thanks. So what did you mean by `Is there some other approach?` ?

Comment: By that I meant. Is there a way to return new reference of callback, without adding dependencies in useMemo method, because I can't re-render map component :). Method that you pointed out, would work in a scenario where re-rendering is not crucial.

Comment: In this case, you would need `shouldComponentUpdate` lifecycle method for React classes components. Since you seem to use function components, you can use React's `memo` function, as explained here : https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-shouldcomponentupdate

Comment: Then, you can update your `Child` component to

`export const Child = memo(({ callback }) => (
  <button onClick={() => callback(1)}>Press!</button>
));`